# Getting assembly error: label or instruction expected at start of line

Tags: ubuntu, assembly, x86, nasm

I'm trying to write a simple program in assembly language (nasm, ubuntu) for adding 2 numbers. I'm stuck with this error

> error: label or instruction expected at start of line

I'm not getting above error on running the code on online compilers. But if try to run the same code in ubuntu environment then I'm stuck with error mentioned.

Code I'm using

```
;The following Program performs addition of two numbers

section .data
    msg1 db 'Enter 1st digit: ', 0xa
    len1 equ $-msg1
    msg2 db 'Enter 2nd digit: ', 0xa
    len2 equ $-msg2
    msg3 db 'The sum is: '
    len3 equ $-msg3

section .bss
    num1 resb 2
    num2 resb 2
    res  resb 1

section .text
    global _start       ;must be declared for using gcc

_start:                 ;tell linker entry point

    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, msg1
    mov edx, len1
    mov eax, 4  
    int 0x80

    mov ebx, 0
    mov ecx, num1
    mov edx, 2
    mov eax, 3  
    int 0x80

    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, msg2
    mov edx, len2
    mov eax, 4  
    int 0x80

    mov ebx, 0
    mov ecx, num2
    mov edx, 2
    mov eax, 3  
    int 0x80

    ;O/Ps "The sum is:"
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, msg3
    mov edx, len3
    mov eax, 4  
    int 0x80

    ;moving the first number to eax register and second number to ebx and subtracting ascii '0' to convert it into a decimal number
    mov eax, [num1]
    sub eax, '0'
    mov ebx, [num2]
    sub ebx, '0'

    ;add eax & ebx then add '0' to convert the sum from decimal to ASCII
    add eax, ebx
    add eax, '0'

    ;storing the sum in memory location res
    mov [res], eax

    ;print the sum
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, res
    mov edx, 1
    mov eax, 4
    int 0x80

    ;Exit
    mov eax, 1
    int 0x80
```

Comment: In what line is the error?

Comment: It shows error at `line 1`

Comment: What command line you used and what nasm version. Also check for copy-paste errors, nonprintable or unicode stuff.

Comment: How do you assemble the code? What is the commands you run to build it?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm using this command `nasm -f elf 6add.asm
` where 6add is the name of the assembly code file.

Comment: @Jester nasm version 2.11.08

Comment: Grabbed nasm 2.11.08 from the ubuntu repository, works fine. Check your source file. I copied from your question, file is 1356 bytes, md5 hash `b0996bdb9c779dea2b40875e7414fb5a`.

Comment: maybe some UTF-8 BOM tag at the beginning? Try to use hexa viewer to see what is at the beginning of the file (first few bytes, until reaching `;The ...`, if there's not thing and the file starts immediately with ";" byte, then it should compile).

Comment: Then what *editor* are you using to edit the code? Does it add some "invisible" characters first in the file? Like an [UTF-8 BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Byte_order_mark)?

Comment: Yeah, just checked, BOM does cause that error with nasm.