# NASM on Windows errors on first line of UTF-8 source no matter what it is: hello.asm:1: error: parser: instruction expected

Tags: windows, assembly, cmake, utf-8, nasm

I'm trying to compile assembly code with NASM using CMake-generated project for Visual Studio on Windows 11.

I ran `nasm -f win64` directly from the command line and it reports the same error as from VS:

```
hello_world.asm:1: error: parser: instruction expected
```

My assembly code (for 32-bit Linux, not Windows):

```
section .text
   global _start    ; необходимо для линкера (ld)
    
_start:             ; сообщает линкеру стартовую точку
   mov  edx,len     ; длина строки 
   mov  ecx,msg     ; строка
   mov  ebx,1       ; дескриптор файла (stdout)
   mov  eax,4       ; номер системного вызова (sys_write)
   int  0x80        ; вызов ядра
    
   mov  eax,1       ; номер системного вызова (sys_exit)
   int  0x80        ; вызов ядра 
 
section .data
msg db 'Hello, world!', 0xa  ; содержимое строки для вывода
len equ $ - msg              ; длина строки
```

I tried to run build with all possible presets (Debug/Release/x86/x64 etc.) but still no results.

---

My NASM build is `2.16.02rc6`. I asked another programmer to assemble this code for me with exact same parameters and NASM build and it worked for him.

Even the program below cannot be assembled, with exact same error as before

```
section .text
global main
main:
    ret
```

Comment: If you don't have an error message from nasm then run it from a command window to see what nasm complains about. By the way that is linux code it won't work on windows even if you manage to assemble it.

Comment: @Jester ran nasm.exe directly. It tells me "hello_world.asm:1: error: parser: instruction expected". Yes, I know that it is Linux code, I'm just trying to test it. I tried to assemble a program with single instruction (ret) and still doesn't work with same error. I asked another person to assemble this code and it worked fine for him.

Comment: That is probably because you saved the file as unicode with a BOM. nasm doesn't like that. Make sure it's ascii or at least no BOM.

Comment: @Jester you saved my soul. Changing file encoding indeed helped. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Jester could you post an answer so I can pin it?

Comment: Duplicate of [Getting assembly error: label or instruction expected at start of line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41429530), but that was also only answered in comments.  The error message is maybe unique enough (if people include the line number when searching) that it could be useful to have an answer posted somewhere.

Comment: Just FYI, this code uses 32-bit Linux system calls via `int 0x80`; unless you configured Visual Studio to run `nasm -felf32` to make 32-bit binaries for WSL2, it's just going to crash if you run it in a native Windows executable.

Comment: @PeterCordes posted an answer by myself. And yes, I know it is Linux code, I was trying to assemble it just for test. Anyways, thanks for a tip.

Comment: Thanks for writing this up.  I made some edits to include things that might let future readers find it, and remove things that were specific to your case.  I hope your IDE showed you the `error: parser: instruction expected` error when it failed to build, not *just* something useless reporting the exit status of `nasm`, whic doesn't tell you *how* it failed.  Once you start editing your source code manually, and introducing typos and brain farts, you're going to need to figure out how to get your IDE to show you NASM's error messages **and warnings**, vital even for experienced users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assembly source file was encoded in UTF-8 [with BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).
NASM doesn't accept a BOM, only plain UTF-8 or ASCII.
(It does allow non-ASCII UTF-8 for things like label names and comments.)

Changing the source file encoding to ASCII resolved the issue.